# Can we compare two java collections with dynamic equals method?

Tags: collections, apache-commons

Lets say we have a '**Client**' object:

## (am just mentioning the attributes and the equals method alone of the 'Client' object below!!)

```
public class Client {
    private Long clientId;
    private String clientName;
    private Integer status;

    //getters and setters for above attributes
    .....
    ...

    //hashCode method
    ....
    ..

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Client other = (Client) obj;
        if (clientId == null) {
            if (other.clientId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!clientId.equals(other.clientId))
            return false;
        if (clientName == null) {
            if (other.clientName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!clientName.equals(other.clientName))
            return false;
        if (status == null) {
            if (other.status != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!status.equals(other.status))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

From the above equals method itz clear that **'two' client objects are said to be equal if all the attributes of the two objects are identical.**

Now assume a scenario where I need to compare two collections(named say incomingClients and existingClients) of Client objects.
The first collection(Collection incomingClients) was generated after reading the 'client' data from a csv/xls file.
The second collection(Collection existingClients) contains, all the existing clients currently in the system.

I can do the following code (using apache CollectionUtils)to get the 'common' clients.

```
Collection<Client> commonClients = (Collection<Client>)CollectionUtils.intersection(incomingClients,existingClients);
```

Now with the below code I can remove these commonClients from both the collections.

```
incomingClients.removeAll(commonClients);
existingClients.removeAll(commonClients);
```

The intention of removing the 'common clients objects' was that, we dont need to do 'any processing' for these records, 
as we are really not at all interested in those records.

Now how can I figure out which are the entirely 'new clients' in the 'Collection incomingClients' collection?
**(When I say 'new' it means a client having a new 'clientId' which doesnt exist in the 'Collection existingClients')**

Also, how can I figure out which are the clients which needs 'modification' 
**(When I say 'modification' it means that the 'Collection incomingClients' and Collection existingClients'
have the same clientId, but, say, different 'clientName')**

I know that we can do the normal 'for' loop('check below') to figure out the 'new'/'modification needed' clients.

## But I thought of writing 'something new', whether we can achieve this using some classes/function in the 'Apache CollectionUtils' package.

```
Collection<Client> newClients = new ArrayList<Client>();
Collection<Client> toBeModifiedClients = new ArrayList<Client>();
boolean foundClient = false;
Client client = null;
for(Client incomingClient :incomingClients){
    foundClient = false;
    for(Client existingClient : existingClients){
    if(existingClient.getClientId().equals(incomingClient.getClientId())){
        client = existingClient;
        foundClient = true;
        break;
    }
   }
   if(foundClient){
        toBeModifiedClients.add(client);
    }else{
        //not found in existing. so this is completely new
        newClients.add(incomingClient);
    }
}
```

Am I 'complicating' a simple stuff??
Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

First, yes, you are complicating "simple stuff". Your entire question could be summarized as follows:

> Given collections A and B, how can I get the following using `CollectionUtils`:
>
> 1. A-B, using a particular function that determines equality
> 2. A∩B, using a particular function that determines equality

So, yes. `CollectionUtils` has what you need. Look at `CollectionUtils.select()`.